# Find web.config location

Tags: iis, web-config, setup-project

Given virtual directory and port can you find the actual path of a web application?
I can get the virtual directory and port via a visual studio setup project, and I'd like to make some modification to the web.config file after install (using a custom action).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [DirectoryEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.aspx) class:

```
using (var entry = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://server/W3SVC/1/root/VirtualDirectoryName"))
{
    var physicalPath = entry.Properties["Path"].Value;
}
```

Comment: This is good stuff, but I get "The RPC server is unavailable." when I execute it.

Comment: Is there a firewall on the server that might be blocking incoming WMI connections? Check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa822854(VS.85).aspx